# Can I use splatting to pass arguments to a non-powershell executable?

Tags: powershell

Can I do something like this?

```
$splatting_table = @{
   "-parameter" = "value"
   "-parameter2" = "value2"
}
.\external-command.exe @splatting_table
```

as an equivalent for

```
.\external-command.exe -parameter value -parameter2 value2
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While it is *technically* possible to use a *hashtable* for [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) with *external programs*, it will rarely work as intended.<sup>[1]</sup>

Instead, **use an *array***:

```bash
$splatting_array = 
   '-parameter', 'value',
   '-parameter2', 'value2'

.\external-command.exe @splatting_array
```

Note that `$splatting_array` is simply a flat array - formatted for readability in element pairs - whose elements PowerShell passes as individual arguments.

---

<sup>[1] With hashtable-based splatting, do *not* include the `-` sigil in the key names (e.g., use `parameter`, not

`-parameter`); aside from that, PowerShell will join your entries with a `:` when constructing the command line for the external program, which few programs support; e.g., hash-table entry `parameter = 'value'` translates to

`-parameter:value`.</sup>